# Windows 10: Fastest way to Switch Resolutions

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have a triple monitor set up that I have configured through my NVidia card to display as one giant 5760x1080 screen. However for some tasks I find it best to let the 2 side monitors go to sleep and use 1 monitor at 1920x1080; especially for programs that don't work well with my widescreen setup.

For example, some programs I use default to full screen on initialization which stretches everything out, which results in a dizzying, awkward look. Luckily, some programs can be configured to run in a set resolution, but there are a handful of programs I use regularly that don't have such resolution options natively.

**Question:** To find a robust solution to this problem, I want to find the fastest way to change the resolution of the windows 10 OS itself. That way no matter which program I run, it will work as expected. The question is how do I do that? I'm hoping there is a command prompt line I can run or something else that is very fast. Currently I'm pointing and clicking as fast as I can in this manner:

Desktop > Display Settings > Resolution > 1920 x 1080 (then I have to click "Keep Changes")

Over a while, the time I spend pointing and clicking is adding up. That's why I would like to find a hot key or other fast method.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17604/change-desktop-resolution-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/) out.

Answer (score 1):

Download:

- [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

Create folder in your preferred location (Main Menu?) and make short-cuts to preferred resolution change invocations in this folder.

For example:

```
nircmd.exe monitor:1 setdisplay 800 600 24
nircmd.exe cmdshortcut "path.to.your.folder" "Monitor#1_800x600x24" setdisplay monitor:1 800 600 24
```

*NirCmd commands reference is contained in `chm` file.*

You can also combine (change `notepad` to desired application):

```
nircmd.exe monitor:1 setdisplay 800 600 24
notepad
nircmd.exe monitor:1 setdisplay 1024 768 24
```

in a single bath file.

Comment: the OP's title is misleading. He doesn't actually want to change the resolution but just need to turn off the 2 screens

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Argh... When you sum up resolutions that starts make sense :|  So AutoIt/AutoHotKey then...